# why does a blank line occupy to two bytes?

Tags: c++, istream, seekg

I'm new to C++. I'd like to count the blank lines at the end of a text file. But now i meet a problem. The contents of the text file are like:

test.txt

```
1
2
blank line
```

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile("test.txt",ios::in);
    if (!inFile.good())
    {
        cout << "error" << endl;
    }

    inFile.clear();
    inFile.seekg(-1, ios::end);
    char a;
    inFile.get(a);
    cout << "symbol for a: " << a << "ASCII: " << (int)a << endl;

    inFile.clear();
    inFile.seekg(-2, ios::end);
    char b;
    inFile.get(b);
    cout << "symbol for b: " << b << "ASCII: " << (int)b << endl;
}
```

The result is:

```
symbol for a: // a stands for the last character which is '\n'
ASCII: 10
symbol for b: // b stands for the second last character, which should be "2"
ASCII: 10
```

In the result shown above, the value of `b` is also `\n`. Why?

Comment: Open your file in binary mode if you want to do these `seekg` things.  A file opened in text mode and using `seekg` will hold surprises for you.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, a newline generates two ascii characters "\r\n" (carriage return, line feed) [10,13]
Open any source code in a hex editor and youll see the TWO chars at the end of each line.

Comment: Thank you so much! But why is the value of 'b' also '\n' instead '\r'?

Comment: My preferred file manipulation is via stdio.h using stdout so Im not so familiar with iostream but Im wondering if the seek end - 2 is correct because if youve read a character already then the end becomes the next character in the buffer if I recall. Id also take note about opening files in text mode like Paul suggests. fopen(file,'t+') behaves in fashions that makes me do things fopen(file,'w+') instead to avoid unneccessary complications.